# API Gateway: Lambda Integration content-disposition header to interpolate values from $context

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless, response-headers

I am trying to set the filename of a CSV which is downloaded from API gateway, the file name is fine if I hardcode it and set the `Content-Disposition` header in my `serverless.yaml` but I need to set the filename dynamically based on the current date and one of the request parameters which is passed to the API when it is invoked.

I am looking at this page: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#custom-response-headers which says that it is possible to use the integration response variables for your header values.

This AWS page is then referenced: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-response-parameters which seems to suggest I can get the request time and the values from the remapped request, although when I try different variants such as `$context.requestOverride.querystring.my_param` or `context.requestOverride.querystring.my_param` it always renders as a literal string.

Here is a code snippet which hopefully demonstrates what I am trying to do:

```
integration: lambda
response:
  headers:
    Content-Type: "'text/csv'"
    Content-Disposition: "'attachment; filename=my_filename_$context.requestOverride.querystring.my_param_$context.requestTime.csv'"
```

I do not want to use lambda proxy integration if it is possible to use one of the query parameters and the request time to generate my file name but I need to interpolate the values into the string which forms the `Content-Disposition` header value.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I did not manage to do this from the serverless config, so if you figure out please answer my question!